# react-native app crashed after using MaxBox Camera Component

Tags: react-native, mapbox

Long time lurker, first time asking...
I know the basics of npm or react-native, and I know even less when taking about using other API integrations. But I'm developing an app that includes a map with the coordinates to a place on one of it's screens. For the map I'm using MapBox

Part of my code used to look like this and it sort of worked. It displayed a map, but I couldn't actually display the coordinates I wanted.

```
import Mapbox from '@rnmapbox/maps';
...
          <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
            <Mapbox.MapView
              style={styles.map}
              projection="globe"
              styleURL={styleURL}
              logoEnabled={false}
              focusable={true}/>
          </View>
```

but now when I add a camera like this:

```
          <View style={styles.mapContainer}>
            <Mapbox.MapView
              style={styles.map}
              projection="globe"
              styleURL={styleURL}
              logoEnabled={false}
              focusable={true}>
              <Mapbox.Camera
                zoomLevel={12}
                centerCoordinate={post.coordinates}
              />
            </Mapbox.MapView>
          </View>
```

It loads the page for a bit. Tries to load the map, and then it crashes. The worst part is that it's not even displaying any type of errors or warnings. It just closes the app. I suppose that the camera is not meant to be used like this, but if that's so, how do I actually do it?

Other info:
npm: 10.2.4
react: 18.2.0
react-native: 0.73.2,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add the coordinates. The error was due to them. I got the coordinates from google map [x,y] but I was not aware that mapbox used them as [y,x] so after changing the order the app stopped crashing!